# Checkout button in Magento not working after I upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7. - Am I missing something?

Tags: magento, checkout

> The store works when I add an item, but when I click to checkout the link re-directs to the home page store. It’s the same when I click on Proceed to checkout. Before, I had the cache management disabled and now is enabled. Is this related or what could be causing this problem? Thanks so much for the help, with kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fixed and these where the steps I took to make it work. However, before you do any of the following work disable your cache management:

1. Open Magento admin panel
2. Go to System>Cache Management
3. Check all Cache types and in the Actions box select refresh
4. Then select all Cache types and in the Actions box select disable
5. Also click Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage buttons
   Now you are free to perform any changes to your store.

Now, if you upgraded and nothing works make sure that under:

System/Configuration -> Web – Default Pages /that your ‘Home page’ is listed under 
‘CMS Home Page’.  Also check:
System/Configuration -> Design – Packages /that your ‘Template’ is listed under 
‘Current Package Name’. Otherwise default takes over.

Note: your template will still come up with all its features and buttons in your browser, even if no home page is setup; this is because of the previous version configuration.

If the ‘Home Page’ and ‘Template’ are not listed, add them and go into your File System and erase everything under ‘var/cache’ and ‘var/session’.  Reload your home page: www.yourstore.com/magento/  it should work. After, all work is done enable your cache management.

Also, it’s good to check that your home page lands at the store, and to check - do the following:

1. Login to your Magento MySQL database.
2. Open the db [database_prefix] for your store.
3. Locate core_config_data.
4. Find the row with entry:  'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' they should look like www.yourstore.com/magento/   or whatever you name your magento store file.

Comment: I was having SECURE Base URL prefixed with http://, changed it to https:// and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try deleting all the cache files stored in the /var/cache folder in magento.
2. Using chrome console or firebug check to see if you have any JS error before redirecting
3. Check your web logs to see if you have any php errors on the checkout page

Comment: Thanks a lot, I deleted everything and check on the button, it looks ok. As far as the error logs I get this: client denied by server configuration: app/etc/local.xml Any ideas?

Comment: @Jacman That error is fine.  Everytime you log into admin Magento checks to make sure that local.xml is not visible to the web.  That error is just the web server reporting that Magento tried and failed to access it.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely to be a Javascript issue when the checkout button does not work. Remove your theme to fall back to the base theme then see if it works.